# How to print a bill in c#

Tags: c#, xml, crystal-reports

I created a simple billing software and stored my bills in an xml file not a database,
i want to giv the possibility tto creat a pdf of a bill but in crystale report all i see is ado dataset and my object i dont know how to select my data?
and all the video i watched was about database

Comment: i instaled crystal report and created a report but when i want to select my data i dont see it

Comment: Well maybe you should use a database?

Answer (score -1):

Convert your xml to valid DataSet and pass it on your CrystalReport obj.
Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311566/how-to-read-xml-data-into-a-dataset-by-using-visual-c-.net

```
string myXMLfile = "C:\\MySchema.xml";
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
try
{
    ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
    dataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
    dataGrid1.DataMember = "Cust";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```